# jQuery UI - table tbody not sortable() on JS-generated HTML (npm webpack app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, npm, webpack

I have a table built in JS. The data in the table is populated by a JSON file after a fetch request. I'd like to be able to drag and drop these tbodys and eventually be able to update the JSON file after each relocation.

I've decided to use jquery-ui to handle the sorting. From what I understand looking at other examples, .sortable() comes with drag and drop. For example, this is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q98d6pcn/6/) that shows .sortable() drag and drop working just fine with hardcoded HTML (movie 1, movie 2, ...).

But when it comes to dynamically JS-generated HTML, tbodys can be picked up and dragged around, but they can't be dropped? What gives? Any help on this is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

This is what I have so far:

**getMovies.js**

```
const getMovies = () => {
     return fetch('/api/movies')
.then(response => response.json());
};

module.exports = getMovies;
```

**db.json**

```
 {
 "movies": [
 {
  "title": "Movie 1",
  "rating": "5",
  "id": 1
},
{
  "title": "Movie 2",
  "rating": "5",
  "id": 2
},
{
  "title": "Movie 3",
  "rating": "5",
  "id": 3
},
{
  "title": "Movie 4",
  "rating": "5",
  "id": 4
}]}
```

**index.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/droppable';

import getMovies from './getMovies.js';

const generateMovieList = () => {
    getMovies().then((movies) => {

    let html = '<table id="movie-list">';
        html += '<thead>';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<th>Film</th>';
        html += '</tr>';
        html += '</thead>';

        movies.forEach(({title}) => {
            console.log(title);
            html += `<tbody>`;
            html += `<tr><td>${title}</td></tr>`;
        });

        html += `</tbody>`;
        html += `</table>`;


        $('.container').html(html);


        $('tbody').sortable();


}).catch((error) => {
    alert('Check console for errors');
    console.log(error);
});
};
generateMovieList();
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <!--this will be generated-->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "dev": "concurrently 'webpack-dev-server --open' 'json-server -d1200 
  --watch db.json'",
  "build": "webpack -p",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node server.js"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "description": "",
 "dependencies": {
 "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
 "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
 "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.2",
 "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
 "jquery": "^3.2.1",
 "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
 "jquery-validation": "^1.17.0",
 "json-server": "^0.11.2",
 "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
 "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
 "webpack": "^3.0.0",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0",
 "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a new tbody tag for every movie.

So instead of doing this:

```
    movies.forEach(({title}) => {
        console.log(title);
        html += `<tbody>`;      ///////////////// this line
        html += `<tr><td>${title}</td></tr>`;
    });

    html += `</tbody>`;
    html += `</table>`;
```

You should create the tbody tag before iterating over movies like this:

```
    html += `<tbody>`;
    movies.forEach(({title}) => {
        console.log(title);
        html += `<tr><td>${title}</td></tr>`;
    });

    html += `</tbody>`;
    html += `</table>`;
```

Comment: *facepalm*. You're right. Thank you so much, I appreciate it!